# Javascript AJAX timeout over 2 Sec is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this function for sending data to my (localhost) server. However, when Wamp was accidentally stopped (localhost server down) I noticed that timeout is not working properly.

If I set the timeout to 2000 mS, the callback is called normally like is supposed. If I set to 4000 mS, the timeout is never called. Instead, readystate will reach 4 (DONE) but with no meaning HTTP status (zero?).

The debug is as follows:

```
READY STATE: 2 STATUS: 0  
READY STATE: 4 STATUS: 0
```

This is normal or do I miss something here? 
I use Firefox latest, 53. Thanks.

```
function ServerSend(url) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // In Internet Explorer, the timeout property may be set only after calling the open() method and before calling 
    // the send() method.

    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.timeout = 4000;

    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
              ShowInfo(xhr.responseText)
        }

        // DEBUG
        {
              console.log("READY STATE: "+xhr.readyState+" STATUS: "+xhr.status);
        }

    };


    xhr.ontimeout = function () { 

        xhr.abort();
        alert("Timed out!!!"); 

        //ShowInfo("Server timeout");
    };


    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you've found an intermediary point whereby the browser has time to recognise that there's nothing listening at the other end, so technically the request is completing but in a failed state, rather than timing out waiting for a response

Comment: Sort of, indeed, in Mozilla docs they say about "failed" but I cannot find a reference to proper detect the failed state. So perhaps 0 (zero) status will means failed or "no status".

Comment: a failed state would be where there is a response but the status is not 200 (OK).

Comment: It makes sense that the status code is not set - it is after all a status from the server.  In your case, there is no server.  Take a look at some of the other `xhr` properties - there may be one more related to the underlying request, rather than the response.  Or perhaps the [`error` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/error) will give you what you need.

Comment: Well, still not clear but implemented 0 checking as fail (unreachable) and != 200 as server fail (and indicate exact code). Thanks both.